# Angular js DatePicker

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, datepicker

I am facing some problem in choosing angular datepicker.I tried with following datepickers.Each has its own problem.
I need something that will be helpful through out the application.

1. Following is actually good, but too plain interface.

   http://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/

2.Following does not have some of basic properties.It seems this is more focused on time and high end functionalities.

```
https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

3.Mainly no UTC mode.Please find TODO list in comment of file.

```
https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/datepicker/datePicker.js
```

4.There is  basic datepicker but not good looking one.Even my boss didn't like it.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/raving/k0po5q44/
```

Please suggest me some better datepicker which can be used through out  angular project application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular Material Datepicker component:
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

To use it you have to have the ngMaterial and ngMessages dependencies.

For example:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);
```

And to use in your view:

```
<div flex-gt-xs>
 <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
 <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```